# Pipe inputs from more than 1 process

Tags: pipe, make, xargs, for

I am trying to automate some make commands. Along with the target we have a variable that is passed to make (corresponding to set of a `#ifdef`'s in code).

The make command looks like this:

```
make <target> <MYCDEF=val>
```

`val` can take multiple values (**MYCDEF_VAL1**, **MYCDEF_VAL2**...).

`target` can also take multiple values like: **android_arm**, **windows_x86**, **linux_x64** etc.

The **MYCDEF_VALn** can be found from a **`config.h`** where we check for

```
#elif (defined MYCDEF_VALn)
```

So, I can get all **MYCDEF** values using `gawk -f script1 config.h`

**script1**:

```
{
    if(/defined.*MYCDEF_/)
    {
        k=index($0, "MYCDEF_");
        print substr($0, k, index($0, ")")-k) #all lines of type defined(MYC_DEF_VALn)
    }
}
```

To get all targets, I can read **`Makefile`** using `gawk -F: -f script2 Makefile`

**script2**:

```
{if(/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+:$/) print $1}
```

To build for all **MYCDEF_** vals with one target I can pipe the output from first script (using **`config.h`**):

```
gawk -f script1 config.h | xargs -I {} -n 1 make -kj windows_x86 MYCDEF={}
```

Similarly for all targets with one **MYCDEF_val**, I can pipe from second script (using Makefile).

```
gawk -f script2 Makefile| xargs -I {} -n 1 make -kj {} MYCDEF=MYCDEF_VAL1
```

Now, we want to build with all values of **MYCDEF_** for all targets. It can be done using for loop:

```
for i in $(gawk -f script2 Makefile)
do
    gawk -f script1 config.h | xargs -I {} -n 1 make -kj $i MYCDEF={}
done
```

Is there a oneliner for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU Parallel:

```
parallel -j1 make -kj {1} MYCDEF={2} :::: <(gawk -f script2 Makefile) <(gawk -f script1 config.h)
```

`-j1` forces GNU Parallel to run the jobs in serial (which is probably what you want given the command you run is `make`).

Comment: works perfect for my requirement. Thank you!!

Comment: I should also be thanking for "parallel" itself!!